# How to remove punctuation and numbers during TweetTokenizer step in NLP?

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize

I am relatively new to `NLP` so please be gentle. I 
have a complete list of the text from Trump's tweets since taking office and I am tokenizing the text to analyze the content.

I am using the `TweetTokenizer` from the `nltk` library in python and I'm trying to get everything tokenized except for numbers and punctuation. Problem is my code removes all the tokens except one.

I have tried using the .`isalpha()` method but this did not work, which I thought would as should only be True for strings composed from the alphabet.

```py
#Create a content from the tweets
text= non_re['text']
#Make all text in lowercase
low_txt= [l.lower() for l in text]

#Iteratively tokenize the tweets
TokTweet= TweetTokenizer()
tokens= [TokTweet.tokenize(t) for t in low_txt
        if t.isalpha()]
```

My output from this is just one token. 
If I remove the if `t.isalpha()` statement then I get all of the tokens including numbers and punctuation, suggesting the `isalpha()` is to blame from the over-trimming.

What I would like, is a way to get the tokens from the tweet text without punctuation and numbers. 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you post some text from the tweets and what exactly you want to keep and what to remove?

Comment: Preprocessing in NLP usually requires some understanding of Python Regex packages. At least my lecturer thought so during the text mining module. I suggest to try to establish a basic understanding of regex in python

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try something like below:

```
import string
import re
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import TweetTokenizer

tweet = "first think another Disney movie, might good, it's kids movie. watch it, can't help enjoy it. ages love movie. first saw movie 10 8 years later still love it! Danny Glover superb could play"

def clean_text(text):
    # remove numbers
    text_nonum = re.sub(r'\d+', '', text)
    # remove punctuations and convert characters to lower case
    text_nopunct = "".join([char.lower() for char in text_nonum if char not in string.punctuation]) 
    # substitute multiple whitespace with single whitespace
    # Also, removes leading and trailing whitespaces
    text_no_doublespace = re.sub('\s+', ' ', text_nopunct).strip()
    return text_no_doublespace

cleaned_tweet = clean_text(tweet)
tt = TweetTokenizer()
print(tt.tokenize(cleaned_tweet))
```

output:

```
['first', 'think', 'another', 'disney', 'movie', 'might', 'good', 'its', 'kids', 'movie', 'watch', 'it', 'cant', 'help', 'enjoy', 'it', 'ages', 'love', 'movie', 'first', 'saw', 'movie', 'years', 'later', 'still', 'love', 'it', 'danny', 'glover', 'superb', 'could', 'play']
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
# Function for removing Punctuation from Text and It gives total no.of punctuation removed also
# Input: Function takes Existing fie name and New file name as string i.e 'existingFileName.txt' and 'newFileName.txt'
# Return: It returns two things Punctuation Free File opened in read mode and a punctuation count variable.


from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import string


def removePunctuation(tokenizeSampleText, newFileName):
    stringPun = list(string.punctuation)

    with open(tokenizeSampleText, "r") as existingFile:
        tokenize_existingFile = word_tokenize(existingFile.read())

    count_pun = 0
    words = []
    for word in tokenize_existingFile:
        if word in stringPun:
            count_pun += 1
        else:
            words.append(word)

    with open(newFileName, "w+") as puncRemovedFile:
        puncRemovedFile.write(" ".join(words))

    with open(newFileName, "r") as file:
        yield file.read(), count_pun


punRemoved, punCount = removePunctuation(
    "Macbeth.txt", "Macbeth-punctuationRemoved.txt"
)
print(f"Total Punctuation : {punCount}")
print(punRemoved)
```